# Tensorflow-gpu use only CPU

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have Cuda 9.0 with its respective cuDNN.
I have installed tensorflow-gpu with pip, I use the object-detection_tutorial.py example and it plays the video and everything, but it uses only CPU and nothing of GPU, the video plays very slow.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information. 
What OS do you use?
What Python do you have installed?
Which tutorial did you follow and which steps?

Comment: Did you point out your Cuda installation path in PATH system variable ?